# How can I use an svg file with lots of individual svg's in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, cordova

I downloaded an svg file from http://svg-cards.sourceforge.net/. Its a basic standard deck of playing cards. It's structure looks like this:

```
<defs>
    <g>
        <text></text>
    </g>
</defs>
<g>
    <g id="king_spade">
        <use></use>
    </g>
    ... //50+ more cards
</g>
```

The readme says

> You can access to each either by rendering the file into a pixmap and clipping each card or by using their name with a DOM interface

And then gives this example:

```
<g id="king_spade">
...
</g>
```

OK, great I see the relationship between the two but I don't understand how I can display just one card, since all of the cards are in the same file. Anything I have done has rendered the entire svg file (all 55 cards!)

That includes:

```
<img>
<embed>
<object>
```

**So my question:** How exactly do I do what the readme suggests should be so easy... How do I access the individual cards inside of the group without first displaying the entire file?

Really what I am looking for is almost a way to use it like css. Include it as a resource in my head, and then be able to do in the body of the document `<g id="king_spade"></g>` and have a the card king of spades show up. Can I not use it this way?

**Edit:** I am trying to do this all inside of a phonegap application, so there is no external server I am connecting to. All resources would be located on the phone, so the `ajax` solution below doesn't work because of same origin restrictions.

Comment: Do you work inside one big `<svg>` element, or just want to add a card to regular HTML (for example, to `<div>`)?

Comment: @EgorNepomnyaschih I would prefer the second option.

Answer (score 3):

I've downloaded cards file `svg-cards.svg` to the same folder, and tried something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                url: "svg-cards.svg",
                type: "get",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(svgText) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    parser.async = false;
                    var svgEl = $(parser.parseFromString(svgText, 'text/xml').documentElement);
                    svgEl.css("display", "none");
                    $("body").append(svgEl);
                    var kingSpade = $(svgEl).find("#king_spade").clone();
                    kingSpade.removeAttr("id");
                    $("#mysvg").append(kingSpade);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="500" height="500">
            <g id="mysvg" transform="translate(-2000,-500)"></g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

It shows king spade card inside 500x500 SVG. The weird thing is that their cards are all spread over 2178x1216 area, so they have different coordinates. You must explicitly translate them left and up to adjust their position. Ok, I guess you get the idea.

Comment: Tested in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

Comment: I'm trying to do this inside of a local app, (i.e. without a server) so this isn't an option because I get the same origin access denied error. Any suggestions on how I could do it otherwise?

Comment: I didn't think that this could be such a problem. See solution in separate answer below. But that way not as elegant as first one, because you'll need to copy-paste entire SVG to your HTML. I still recommend you to setup a server if you are working on web development.

Answer (score 0):

The same, but without AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var svgEl = $("#sourcesvg");
                svgEl.css("display", "none");
                var kingSpade = $(svgEl).find("#king_spade").clone();
                kingSpade.removeAttr("id");
                $("#mysvg").append(kingSpade);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="500" height="500">
            <g id="mysvg" transform="translate(-2000,-500)"></g>
        </svg>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
            height="1216.19" width="2178.18" viewBox="-.2 -236 2178.99 1216.19" id="sourcesvg">
            ...
            .....
            ...     // Entire source SVG goes here
            ....
        </svg> 
    </body>
</html>
```